# Creating an array in the custom hook is re rendering value at every state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I was creating a custom hook in react native and encountered a problem with useEffect and useState, resulting in an infinite loop.

I created a little snack to exemplify what is happening:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useMemo } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
   const [testStateVariable, setTestStateVariable] = useState(false);

    const useCustomHookTest = () => {
        let testVar = ""; // Change the value "" to [] to see the problem;
        return useMemo(
            () => ({
                testVar,
            }),
            [testVar],
            );
    };
    
    var { testVar } = useCustomHookTest();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("CHANGE OF testVar!")
    }, [testVar]);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
             <Button title="Change a state to true" onPress={() => {setTestStateVariable(true)}}/>
             <Button title="Change a state to false" onPress={() => {setTestStateVariable(false)}}/>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Basically, when I use an array inside a custom hook, it re-renders and changes the value of the variable every time any state changes.
You can see this changing the value of testVar to [] and press the two buttons to change the states, the useEffect is fired at every state change, but this doesn't happen when the value is "".

I tried using useMemo but it didn't work,

Does someone have a solution for this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic gist is that `"" === ""` is always true, while `[] === []` is always false. Strings, although are like objects, are kind of treated like primitives, in that they will ***always*** be equal to themselves. Arrays on the other hand, are special Javascript objects and two declared objects are never strictly equal to each other.

Try it!

```js
console.log('"" === ""', "" === ""); // true
console.log('[] === []', [] === []); // false
```

When you assign `let testVar = "";` each render cycle the `testVar` is always equal to the last the value from the previous render and and so the `useMemo` hook returns the previously computed, memoized value.

```
const useCustomHookTest = () => {
  let testVar = "";
  return useMemo(
    () => ({
      testVar
    }),
    [testVar] // "" === "" true, dependency didn't "change".
  );
};
```

Contrast this now when you assign `let testVar = "";` each render cycle, the dependency is now *always* a new array reference and thus not strictly equal and the `useMemo` hook recomputes its memoized value.

```
const useCustomHookTest = () => {
  let testVar = []; // <-- new array each render
  return useMemo(
    () => ({
      testVar
    }),
    [testVar] // [] === [] false, new memoized value
  );
};
```

Since the memoized value is a ***new*** object, the dependency for the `useEffect` hook now sees a new object, i.e. `{ testVar: true } === { testVar: false }` isn't false because the `testVar` property changed, but because `{} === {}` is also false for the same reason `[] === []` is. It's a new object reference.

Beyond this it is unclear what you hope to accomplish with the following code pattern:

```
export default function App() {
  const [testStateVariable, setTestStateVariable] = useState(false);

  const useCustomHookTest = () => {
    let testVar = "";
    return useMemo(
      () => ({
        testVar
      }),
      [testVar]
    );
  };

  var { testVar } = useCustomHookTest();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("CHANGE OF testVar!");
  }, [testVar]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{testStateVariable.toString()}</Text>
      <Button
        title="Change a state to true"
        onPress={() => {
          setTestStateVariable(true);
        }}
      />
      <Button
        title="Change a state to false"
        onPress={() => {
          setTestStateVariable(false);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

The `useCustomHookTest` hook is redeclared each render cycle, so anything internal is recreated each render cycle of the parent component.

If your question is basically *how* to use arrays as React hook dependencies then unfortunately there aren't any great solutions. The two leading solutions are either to implement a deep equality check, or to simply JSON stringify the array.

JSON.stringify Example:

```
const useCustomHookTest = () => {
  let testVar = [];
  return { testVar };
};

export default function App() {
  const [testStateVariable, setTestStateVariable] = useState(false);

  const { testVar } = useCustomHookTest();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("CHANGE OF testVar!");
  }, [JSON.stringify(testVar)]); // <-- JSON stringify dependency

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{testStateVariable.toString()}</Text>
      <Button
        title={`Change a state to ${(!testStateVariable).toString()}`}
        onPress={() => {
          setTestStateVariable((t) => !t);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit creating-an-array-in-the-custom-hook-is-re-rendering-value-at-every-state-change]

Comment: Thanks, it worked using the JSON.stringify()!  I needed to set a state in the component every time the value from the custom hook changed, but since changing a state made the custom hook execute again, it was entering in an infinite loop.